# Access php array inside vue.js template

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to learn Laravel and vue.js and stumbled upon a problem. I have this Laravel model which contains a php method that fetches data from a database and puts into objects which are then put into an array. I would then like to access this array inside a vue.js component, but I dont know how I am supposed to do that.

1. My Laravel model fetches data from the database and puts into objects in an array
2. I can print out the array, without using vue, from my index.blade.php like this:

   ```
   @foreach ($data['hosts'] as $hostsKey => $hostsValue)
       <ul>
           @foreach ($hostsValue as $hostKey => $hostValue)
               <li>{!!$hostKey!!}: {!!$hostValue!!}</li>  
           @endforeach   
       </ul>
   @endforeach
   ```
3. Is it possible to access it inside my vue component by putting this in my index.blade.php instead of the above example?

   ```
   <div id="app">
       <hosts></hosts>
   </div>
   ```

   with the app.js looking something like this:

   ```
   Vue.component('host', require('./components/host.vue').default);

   const app = new Vue({
       el: '#app'
   });
   ```

   and my host.vue looking like this:

   ```
   <template>
       <div>
           {{ hostData }}
       </div>
   </template>

   <script>
       export default {
           data(){
               return{
                   hostData: /* MY PHP VARIABLE HERE */
               }
           }
       }
   </script>
   ```

Started out trying vue today, so please don't be too hard on me.

Comment: I don't speak vue.js, but the general idea of an SinglePageApplication is, that it (vuejs) fetches data from the server when needed through an api.

Comment: Okay. Maybe I should set up an api with laravel first and use that with vue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could modify your component to receive an array as a prop like :

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ hostData }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
       props:['hostData'],
        data(){
            return{

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

in blade template pass your `$data['hosts']` through `host-data` prop :

```php
<div id="app">
    <host :host-data="{{ json_encode($data['hosts']) }}"></host>
</div>
```